# Display File from Google Drive using docs.google.com/gview Embedded in iFrame

Tags: html, iframe, embed, google-docs, viewer

I have a file saved in google drive.

I want to display it on a website embedded in an iframe.

I'm trying to use the google docs viewer, but can't quite get it to work.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url={fileUrl}&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

If I copy the file to an s3 bucket (or anywhere else other than google drive) and use an external link such as `https://s3.../filename.ext` for the `fileUrl` - it works!

But I can't figure out what link to use from Google Drive. The share and edit links don't work.

- `https://drive.google.com/open?id={fileId}` Share Link.
- `https://docs.google.com/document/d/{fileId}/edit` Open/Edit Link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error with a bunch of google drive/docs links, I figured it out.

The trick is using the direct download link. `https://drive.google.com/uc?id={fileId}`

So your iframe src should look like this:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://drive.google.com/uc?id={fileId}&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Comment: is it free for commercial use?

Answer (score 1):

This works, no reload issue .

https://drive.google.com/file/d/(YOUR_FILE_ID)/preview